# How to set Scrolling Movement Method on Text View in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, vertical-scrolling, scrollable

In java we do the following to make the text-view scrollable

```
textview.setMovementMethod (new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

but I am unable to comprehend how to perform the same task in Kotlin.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following syntax:

```
textview.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
```

Comment: Tried it - Unresolved reference: movementMethod

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/ScrollingMovementMethod), use

```
textview.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance()
```